# Only allowing specific packages from one repo

Tags: yum

I'm looking for information on whether there is an easier way to do this.  I have set up a company repo, we use custom packages for a few items.  What I want to avoid is this package being installed or updated from another repo  (base, extras, updates, or any other repo that is installed).

Right now I have in `/etc/yum.conf` under `[main]`:

```
exclude=package*
```

So this solves my above concern.  However, when I actually want to install or update this package from the company repo, I end up having to run:

```
yum --disableexcludes=all --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="company" package
```

This is ugly and prevents yum from using the other repos for dependencies and just `--disableexcludes="company"` didn't work.

So is there a way to exclude "package*" from all repos except "company" **without** having to go into every repo file?

Comment: By the time you get to this point, it may be worth mirroring your OS's package repo, and using `--exclude` options to `rsync` on the copy.

Comment: Seems like overkill.  Fedora, for example, I think has close to 10,000 packages.  This also wouldn't help us if another repo was installed and had a package conflict.

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment instead of an answer: I know it's *more* complex than your current solution. But, you're kind of making your own bed here. You're wanting to grab packages from many different places *but also* control who gives you what. I'm not sure there's a whole lot of value in the middle ground between active and passive stances on software sources. I'm imaging an inverted Gaussian curve with control over packages on the X and utility on the Y. The farther you get from the extremes on X, the less sensible the activity. Best is almost completely passive or active.

Comment: My 2 cents is stick to the public repo, you are setting yourself up for trouble having private repo for the organization. Odds are your organization is getting it's repos from a public source anyway, so why make another middle man. I know.. I know.. "security concerns". Still doesn't make sense to me!

Comment: @Baazigar: Not sure what you mean by "Odds are your organization is getting it's repos from a public source anyway".  We have about 30 custom built RPMs that need to be effectively distributed across serveral hundred servers.  A private repo seems to be the most efficient method.

Comment: Seems like my comment was a little hasty. If you need users to be able to pull these rpms in the future than maybe a repo is the best solution. If it is just for internal use with setup or maintenance, ansible is a super easy and powerful way to distribute.